# How to check for exit code of the ssh tunnel?

Tags: bash, ssh, dd, ssh-tunnel

I have a command of the form:

```
dd if=/my/block/device | ssh myuser@otherserver "gzip > file.gz"
```

How to check if the ssh command failed due to connectivity problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled. If `pipefail` is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

Then from [`man 1 ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> `ssh` exits with the exit status of the remote command or with `255` if an error occurred.

Normally (with `pipefail` disabled) you get exit status of `ssh`. A possible value of `255` may come from `ssh` itself or may come from whatever command you run on the remote side (but "common" errors usually yield "low" exit status, like `1`, `2`). In practice `255` indicates something went very wrong.

Exit status is available as special parameter `$?` just after the pipe exits. Example:

```
$ true | ssh no-such-address.example.org true
# error message here, skipped
$ echo $?
255
```

To get more specific information from `ssh`, you need to analyze its stderr. See the manual, especially `-E` (if available) and `-v` options. `-E` specifies the logfile `ssh` should write to, but you will get similar effect by redirecting stderr with `2>/path/to/logfile`. About `-v`:

> `-v`
>   Verbose mode. Causes `ssh` to print debugging messages about its progress. This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems. Multiple `-v` options increase the verbosity. The maximum is `3`.

So the general procedure is like this: after `ssh` exits, check the exit status; if it's `255`, analyze the `logfile` if the failure is "due to connectivity problems".

Answer (score 0):

Use : `echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}`

Or `echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}` to check the exit status of all commands.

see Examples: [$PIPESTATUS](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html):

> The members of the `$PIPESTATUS` array hold the exit status of each respective command executed in a pipe. `$PIPESTATUS[0]` holds the exit status of the first command in the pipe, `$PIPESTATUS[1]` the exit status of the second command, and so on.