# Verify data integrity of tar outputting through ssh

Tags: ssh, backup, tar, checksum, data-integrity

I am creating a backup script which uses `tar`, encrypts it with `gpg` and then sends the output through `ssh` to an offsite host. I am now wondering weather and how I can verify that all of the data is transmitted successfully. Since the backup is multiple GB in size, there is a reasonable chance the connection might drop mid way. Since `ssh` uses `TCP` I am not worried about some packets being dropped, but what about when the connection is gone for 20 seconds or more?

This is the command I am using:

```
tar \
    --create \
    ... \
    --listed-incremental="${metadata_file}" \
    --file - \
    "${FILES_TO_BACKUP[@]}" |
gpg --encrypt ... --output - |
ssh -T ${REMOTE_HOST} "cat > ${output_file}"
```

---

After the backup I copy the metadata file as well, where I can can use a checksum to verify. But what about the backup itself?

There is the possibility to

1. write the backup to local storage
2. copy to remote
3. verify checksum
4. rm the local backup

However since I don't have that much storage locally I'd like not to that if possible.

I am on Linux with Bash >4.0.

Comment: Why can't you checksum output_file on the remote computer?

Comment: I can do that, however since I dont save the backup locally I dont have a checksum to compare to

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/q/1368341/432690). Note it's for Bash and the answers assume Bash. In Bash `set -o pipefail` and if your pipeline returns 0 then you will know that each utility (`tar`, `gpg`, `ssh` (so the remote shell, so the remote `cat`)) has succeeded.

Comment: Indeed, I am on Linux with Bash >4.0. I will give pipefail a try as well

Comment: `gpg --encrypt` (i.e. encrypt to pubkey), since around 2010, uses [integrity-protected encryption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.13) so if you have the decryption (secret=private) key -- and if you don't the backup is useless -- you can do a trial decrypt, throwing the data to /dev/null, and see if it gives an MDC error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to save the file locally to compute its checksum.

The idea is to add the checksum utility of your choice into the pipe
after `gpg` and before `ssh`, to calculate the checksum locally
without saving it to a local file. To avoid sending the checksum
to `ssh` you may use `tee`.

The idea is that the pipe will look like this :

```
tar ... | gpg ... | tee >(checksum-utility > output-file) | ssh ...
```

For `output-file` you may use a real file or also `/dev/tty`.

See for example the post
[Checksum and pipe an input simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966907/checksum-and-pipe-an-input-simultaneously).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Thanks for the comment, and I modified my answer. I think that the poster will have to experiment with his shell or shells to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know it was possible to calculate the checksum on the fly. Brilliant! I will give this a try but this looks very promising

Comment: I tried this solution, works great. In the end I used `md5sum` in addition to enabling `pipefail` and `set -o`  to be absolutely sure. Tested it, works.

Comment: just as a side note: What would be `/dev/tty` in this case? The terminal I run the command from and not the output on the remote host, right?

Comment: @FelixSchneider [`/dev/tty` is the controlling terminal associated with the process group of the process that opens it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html). In case of `>(checksum-utility >/dev/tty)` the process opening `/dev/tty` is your local shell. So yes, `/dev/tty` is the terminal you run the command from.